# Show image before the start of the function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my image which has to be loaded before the loop

```
<div id="attendenceGridDivLoader" style="display:none">
<img src="<?php echo base_url() . 'images/loader.gif'; ?>" /> 
</div>

<select onchange=checkAll(this.value);></select>
```

What happens is when `checkAll()` function is called the image doesn't get loaded and the loop runs so it hangs my browser for some time and then everything is fine.

What i want is to load the image before the loop starts

```
 function checkAll(el){
     $("#attendenceGridDivLoader").show();
     var hArr= $('.subCheckBox');
    for(x=0;x<hArr.length;x++){
        $('.subCheckBox').val(el);
    }
    if(x==hArr.length){
        $('#attendenceGridDivLoader').hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should bind the onchange function on `window.load`.This will ensure that images gets loaded.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the browser is not getting time to repaint the window after the image display is called

```
function checkAll(el) {
    $("#attendenceGridDivLoader").show();
    //give a little time for the image to get displayed
    setTimeout(function () {
        var hArr = $('.subCheckBox');
        for (x = 0; x < hArr.length; x++) {
            $('.subCheckBox').val(el);
        }
        if (x == hArr.length) {
            $('#attendenceGridDivLoader').hide();
        }
    }, 50)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code doesn't make any sense.

```
//hArr is a selector with checkboxes
var hArr= $('.subCheckBox');
//loop through each checkbox
for(x=0;x<hArr.length;x++){
    //in each iteration, assign a value to every checkbox, again
    $('.subCheckBox').val(el);
}
```

the effect will be the same in this code, but without the O(n*n) complexity and hang times

```
//just set the value to the checkboxes. That's it. No loops, no nothing
$('.subCheckBox').val(el);
```

THIS is the problem you're having, why you think you need the image. This is why it takes long to process.